# TypeScript map with generic abstract object

Tags: typescript

I have several Items that they all inherit from the abstract Item. The object should contain a map with different Item implementations. With my current code I encountered the following error in the Object:

> TS2314: Generic type 'Item<'T'>' requires 1 type argument(s)

In Java, that's not a problem. How do I get this to work in TypeScript?

**Items**

```
abstract class Item<T> {

}


class Item1 extends Item<boolean> {

}


class Item2 extends Item<number> {

}
```

**Object.ts**

```
class Object {
    private itemMap: Map<number, Item>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Object {
    private itemMap: Map<number, Item1 | Item2>;
}
```

If you plan to add new classes extending `Item` and support those in `Object`, you could use `Item<any>`.

It would work for all the generic types for which a derived `Item` class exists; and you couldn't instantiate objects with generic types for which you haven't declared a derived class:

```
class Object {
  private itemMap: Map<number, Item<any>>;

  public constructor() {
    this.itemMap = new Map();
    this.itemMap.set(1, new Item1());         // ok
    this.itemMap.set(2, new Item2());         // ok
    this.itemMap.set(3, new Item<string>());  // Error: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this later, but it seems to be not clean, because if I create new item classes, there are multiple spots where I have to change code.